# Window reload to bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, datatables

Im trying to reload a tabbed page once a dataTable has been rendered using the following statement.

```
window.location.reload()
```

Is it possible to reload straight to the active tab?

Comment: Yes, it is possible!

Comment: Will you mind elaborate your question with the efforts you have taken ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to reload - datatable, tab or the window itself, please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jquery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#containerId").load('your-url');
```